# Versioning/Changelog policy of Angular Router?

Tags: angular

I am confused by the versioning of different Angular 2 modules.

According to [the CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), the current stable version of Angular 2 is 2.2.1.

However the router is - as far as I know - versioned separately. According to NPM, the latest version is 3.2.3. Also, according to NPM, latest version of Angular 2 (e.g. `http` module) is 2.2.3.

Can anyone tell me what's the correct state, and why the router is still versioned separately?

Comment: The router was substantially reworked due to issues in the first design, developed as 2.x, so they bumped to 3.x to make this clear - see e.g. http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/improvements-coming-for-routing-in.html.

Comment: All Angular packages on NPM are 2.2.3. I think that they just forgot to update CHANGELOG. And Router is versioned separately, yes.

Comment: If you want to see changes in 2.2.2 and 2.2.3, you'll have to drill in via https://github.com/angular/angular/releases

Comment: Yes, see [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/380377139b5123d67b3dc5df4e0c87e091da5a59#diff-4ac32a78649ca5bdd8e0ba38b7006a1e).